# Algeba problem with prime numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Give all prime numbers
$
p
$
for which
$
2p + p^{2}
$
is also prime. I'm not really sure what should I do with the information that
$
p
$
is prime, so, how to solve this?

Comment: $2p+p^2=p(2+p)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that we can't have that $$P=p^2+2p=p(p+2)$$ os not a prime because for every $p$ the number $P$ is composite, so tge set of $p$ is empty.

Comment: Why have you put a $-1$? What's wrong?

Comment: I haven't, someone else did.

Comment: But thank you...

Comment: I couldn't favor so fast, and it's on 0 since I liked and it was a -1.